# Is there a method to catch the invoked method in Activity under testing with Espresso

Tags: android, testing, junit, mocking, android-espresso

I'm going to write the test code by using the Espresso library.
But, I couldn't find a workaround for the below testing.

The testing module is Login module.
After checking the user id and password, two methods will be invoked on the LoginActivity.

But, I don't know how to catch the invoked methods....

Below is my testing code snippet.

```
public class LoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

public LoginActivityTest() {
    super(LoginActivity.class);
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
}



public void testLoginSuccess() {
    onView(withId(R.id.username)).perform(typeText("real@user.com"));
    onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(typeText("secret"));
    onView(withId(R.id.loginButton)).perform(click());

    // I think I have to write code snippet down here.
}
```

}

The login activity have a two callback methods by using the interface.

```
@Override
public void loginSuccessful() {
    ...
}

@Override
public void showError() {
}
```

Comment: i've updated answer

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, try to use `Espresso Intents` library.

Check: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html

and this example: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/ui/espresso/IntentsAdvancedSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/espresso/intents/AdvancedSample/ImageViewerActivityTest.java